# columns are not taking correct width on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a grid system with Bootstrap 3.3.7. The width of the container is 1200px.

When I resize the browser window to `< 768 px` the columns on "Grid 1 + 2 + 3" are not reacting to the `col-xs-xx` i set. See the [demo here](http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html).

When I set the columns to have a width on`800 px` instead of `600 px` the width is correct on smaller screens, but the columns do not fit on bigger screens, unless I set a very big height on the columns.

How can I set the columns to get the correct width when the screen is below 768 px?

```css
body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    div { 
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .index-content {
      /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
      /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
    }

    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 350px;
    }

    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .card {
            position: relative;
        }
        .card-content {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        .card-content h4,
        .card-content p {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }
        .card-content a {
            float: right;
        }
        .index-content .card h4,
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 0 20px 15px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    .margin_bottom{
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"]{ 
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px; 
    }
    .row { 
        margin-left: -5px; 
        margin-right: -5px; 
    }
    
    .card-img-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3>Grid 1</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x290" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x290" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Grid 2</h3>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x245" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
      </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Grid 3</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
      <!-- I can change the width to 800px to fit the xs viewport. But then the height on the column om sm viewport have to be 1020 px, which is way to high after my opnion -->
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x610" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you share a screen shot with the problematic view, and what is the expected result? I can't see in your code something about `width: 600px` or `width: 800px`

Comment: Hello Mosh. Please lokke the demosite to see the px width or run the code shippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grids are reacting as they should be. When `col-xx-xx` are nested, they assume their parent containers width to be 100%. You'll find more info on bootstrap doc page [See Two columns with two nested columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/grid/).

Your html code has lot of redundant html `divs`. For ex. your grid 1 can be like this

```
<h3>Grid 1</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x290" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 margin_bottom">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x290" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your dont need both `col-xs-6 col-sm-6`, just `col-xs-6` will get job done.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So that actually means that I do not have control over the grid, when columns are nested?

Comment: You do have control over nested cols. Nesting gives you 12 cols inside that particular div container